# lim sup and sup inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that for a sequence of functions $f_n$

$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty }f_n \leq \sup_{n} f_n$$
I tried to search for this result, but I couldn't find, so maybe my understanding is wrong and this does not hold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inequality
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$$
holds for any real numbers $a_n$, because the definition of $\limsup$ is
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n:=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sup_{n\geq m}a_n\right)$$
and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have
$$\left(\sup_{n\geq m}a_n\right)\leq\sup_{m\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$$
(if the numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_{m-1}$ are less than or equal to the supremum of the others, both sides are equal, and if not, then the right side is larger).Therefore
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\leq \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f_n(x)$$
holds for any real number $x$, which is precisely what is meant by the statement
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n\leq \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f_n.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! My intuition was correct.

Answer (score 0):

this is true. take any x, then for all n $f_n (x) \leq \sup_n f_n(x)$ by definition of supremum, hence also every limit point of any subsequence $f_{n'} (x)$ is also smaller or equal to $\sup_n f_n{(x)}$